# Get selected row item in DataGrid WPF doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, datagrid

Im tring to get Selected row item.
I have been readed that it should be worked :

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Customers}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedCustomer, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

Customer customer = (Customer)myDataGrid.SelectedItem;
```

1. In the first xaml - I put it, it doesnt error or something I just dont know how to use it.. How in the c# code I can get the selected row ?
2. In the C# line code It error. The visual studio doesn't exist Customer.

   I would thankfull to help. :) Thanks.

Comment: The point of binding `SelectedItem` is to be able to access it via your `SelectedCustomer` property, not through the Datagrid in code behind. Place a breakpoint in the setter of `SelectedCustomer` and check if its properly working.

Comment: *I just don't know how to use it*... it is *not* our job to teach you how to write WPF. You need to learn it on your own using books or external resources. Our job is to help you with *specific problems that you face in your programs*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rly hard to know what exactly you wanted :) but here is an example I just put togetter on how to drag info out of the datagrid.
Did not implament alot of those bindings in it so this is pure getting the info.

**Xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Name="dg"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Name="btn" Click="btn_Click" />

</Grid>
```

**Codebehind**

```
    List<SomeInfo> list = new List<SomeInfo>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        list.Add(new SomeInfo() { Name = "PC", Description = "Computer", ID = 1 });
        list.Add(new SomeInfo() { Name = "PS", Description = "Playstation", ID = 2 });
        list.Add(new SomeInfo() { Name = "XB", Description = "Xbox", ID = 3 });
        this.dg.ItemsSource = list;
    }

    public class SomeInfo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }

    private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dg.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
            DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(dg.SelectedIndex);
            DataGridCell RowColumn = dg.Columns[0].GetCellContent(row).Parent as DataGridCell;
            btn.Content = ((TextBlock)RowColumn.Content).Text;
        }
    }
```

the btn_click does all the gathering info stuff where the last 2 makes my datagrid for testing.

Hope it will help you out :)

**------------------Edit--------------------------**

from the comment this below is what you would need only

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dg.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
            DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(dg.SelectedIndex);
            DataGridCell RowColumn = dg.Columns[0].GetCellContent(row).Parent as DataGridCell;
            btn.Content = ((TextBlock)RowColumn.Content).Text;
        }
    }

dg = your datagrid 
dg.Columns[0] = change 0 into what column you want
info from btn.Content = what you want the content to be
```

**--------------EDIT 2------------**
To get the selected row's index all you need is

```
            int index = dg.SelectedIndex;
            btn.Content = index;
```

or if you dont want to store the integar

```
            btn.Content = dg.SelectedIndex;
```

Comment: Sorry but I didnt understand what to write in my code.. There is a lot of variable that not exist in my project..

Comment: private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dg.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
            DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(dg.SelectedIndex);
            DataGridCell RowColumn = dg.Columns[0].GetCellContent(row).Parent as DataGridCell;
            btn.Content = ((TextBlock)RowColumn.Content).Text;
        }
    }

dg = your datagrid
dg.Columns[0] = change 0 into what column you want info from
btn.Content = what you want the content to be

Comment: I will edit the post so you can see a better example of what I just wrote

Comment: I'm need only to get the row index, thats it. For delete update and edit rows.. I'm connection between that datagrid and Access Data base, where in this code is the index of the row ? because nothing here is an int or something

Comment: thats easy just make datagrid.selectedindex.
you can put the value into a int if needed or put it somewere you like to it will give you the index of the selected row
you can check my latest edit for it also

Comment: Oh thanks. The selected row working.Now im in another problem. If you can take a look its will be great. Thanks again :)

Comment: what is your new problem? and no problem :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26297746/delete-row-in-datagrid-connection-to-access-data-base

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I forgot to add the URL for the second question hah :D

Answer (score 0):

The grid defined in a very incomplete. 
Council to explicitly all columns that compose it with the individual binding

In this case I used the event doubleClick but you have to choose the right event to you

By code for example try this:

In XAML add:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" x:FieldModifier="public" MouseDoubleClick="MyDataGrid_MouseDoubleClick" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Customers}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedCustomer, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

And in behind c# code this:

```
private void MyDataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender != null)
            {
                DataGrid grid = sender as DataGrid;
                if (grid != null && grid.SelectedItems != null && grid.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
                {

                        var selectedRow = grid.SelectedItem as MyObject;

                        try
                        {
                            Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;

                            //TODO YOUR OPERATION ON selectdRow
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                             Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
                        }

                }
            }
        }
```